# How add Int value to the Alamofire upload parameters

Tags: json, swift, int, nsdata, alamofire

I want to add `Int` value to the `multipartFormData`:

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST,
                 url,
                 headers: headers,
                 multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    //add some jpg image
                    //add other vaues:
                    for (key, value) in parameters {
                        if value is String {
                            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
                        } else if value is Int {
                            let convertedValueNumber: NSNumber = NSNumber(int: value.intValue)
                            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(convertedValueNumber)
                            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: data, name: key)
                        }
                    }

    }, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
      //some processing
})
```

But server return error that I don't send `Int` value. How do I add `Int` value to the parameters?

Comment: you have option to type cast int to string.

Comment: Your server is really expecting `NSKeyedArchiver` binary plist?!? Most times, the server would just be expecting a string representation of the numeric value.

Comment: @Rob I tried to convert without NSKeyedArchiver I used let data = NSData(bytes: &vInt, length: sizeof(Int))  multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: data, name: key) And this doesn't help

Comment: Is your server _really_ expecting binary payload? Usually it would be string representation (e.g. with string interpolation, `"\(value)"`).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `NSKeyedArchiver` is very curious. Usually you'd just send string representation, e.g.:

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, URL, headers: headers, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    //add some jpg image
    //add other values:
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        if value is String {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        } else if value is Int {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }
    }
}, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    //some processing
})
```

Or, even simpler, because string interpolation works with both `String` and `Int`:

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, URL, headers: headers, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    //add some jpg image
    //add other values:
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        if value is String || value is Int {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }
    }
}, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    //some processing
})
```

Or, in Alamofire 4 with Swift 3:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    //add some jpg image
    //add other values:
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        if value is String || value is Int {
            multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    }
}, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    //some processing
})
```

Comment: Thank's but I got a question what if value could be `[String]`,`[String:Any]` ... if could have many types so should I for each type create the is block ?

Comment: Or you could have this single method that takes accepts both permutations, e.g a `Any?` parameter and then do `if let parameters = parameters as? [String] { ... } else if let parameters = parameters as? [String: String] { ... }`, or whatever.